# Store File in Directory of Drive

Tags: java, store, temporary-files

```
 {
      headFile = File.createTempFile("HMh", ".tmp");
      headCreated = true;
      dataFile = File.createTempFile("HMd",".tmp");
      dataCreated = true;
      headOut = new DataOutputStream((new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(headFile))));
      dataOut = new DataOutputStream((new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dataFile))));
    }
```

I have this code where headOut is being referenced and writing temp File to headFile, I want to replace the temporary File with the File to be stored in Directory in Windows D Drive so as too see the Files being stored physically  . Please help with the code . As it creates multiple Temp File please let know to append the File name with the Date Time value so as it doesent overide existing Temp Files .

Comment: What does "the File to be created in Directory in Windows Drive" mean?  Please edit your question to include an example of such a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
long l  = new Date().getTime();
```

`File.createTempFile("HMh"+l, ".tmp")` It will append timestamps to your file.

Write file on drive.

```
File file = new File("C:\\filename.txt");
// creates the file
file.createNewFile();
// creates a FileWriter Object
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file); 
// Writes the content to the file
writer.write("This\n is\n an\n example\n");
```

Comment: [Windows does not allow colons (':') in file names.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions)

Comment: I want to replace the temporary files being created to text files and store it into Windows drive

Comment: you have to read your `.temp` file first using `FileReader` then write that file on expected location on `window` drive.

Comment: How do we write Files to Drive . Googled but confused .

Comment: I have updated my answer, this code write your file on `C` drive.